# How to expose an entity via alternate keys with spring data rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Spring-data-rest does a great job exposing entities via their primary key for `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` etc. operations.

```
/myentityies/123
```

It also exposes search operations.

```
/myentities/search/byMyOtherKey?myOtherKey=123
```

In my case the entities have a number of alternate keys.  The systems calling us, will know the objects by these IDs, rather than our internal primary key.  Is it possible to expose the objects via another URL and have the `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` handled by the built-in `spring-data-rest` controllers?

```
/myentities/myotherkey/456
```

We'd like to avoid forcing the calling systems to have to make two requests for each update.

I've tried playing with `@RestResource` path value, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add additional paths.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to do this!

Add an implementation of [BackendIdConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/spi/BackendIdConverter.html) to your Spring context.

```
@Component
public class BackendIdConverterImpl implements BackendIdConverter {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> delimiter) {
    return true; // Always convert.
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable fromRequestId(String id, Class<?> entityType) {
    // Convert from the external key to your internal key.
  }

  @Override
  public String toRequestId(Serializable id, Class<?> entityType) {
    // Convert from the internal key to your external key.
  }

}
```

Comment: It is not exactly what was asked: if you use that, /myentityies/123 will not respond any more, and only /myentityies/456 will do.
And I think it is dangerous to always return true in supports, it should be only for the class you wants to convert (eg MyEntity)

Answer (score -1):

You think in URI, and Spring Data Rest in designed to think in relations.

There is no problem in declaring another controller, using `@RepositoryRestController` mapped on

```
/myentities/myotherkey/{otherKey}
```

but then, how will it be discovered by the client application ?  To be consistent, you'll have to add a link to this controller in your resource mapping, with a custom `ResourceProcessor<Resource<Myentity>>`.

But no pre-made stuff here. In a REST environment, the ID of an entity is supposed to be its URI. If you want to have another paradigm, then you will have to adapt it yourself, unfortunately.